# ssh from host to guest in VMWare without host static ip

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, vmware

I have a windows 7 host and a QNX (essentially unix) guest that i would like to communicate with. Currently I am able to SSH from the host to the guest if i have a static network adapter setting. ie:

[image]

This is the QNX network settings (This is set up with a bridge adapter)

And windows is set to the same network with a static ip (192.168.1.90 with subnet 255.255.255.0)

If i have it set up this way then I can successfully ssh from the windows host to the VM with openSSH or PuTTY. But this means my network adapter is useless and I cannot connect to the Internet. I am wondering if there is a way to ssh to a VMWare guest when the host has a auto dhcp ip address? I have tried this and it does not work, but maybe there is some work around?

Note: The network cannot be changed to suit my static ip as it is an organisational network.

Comment: Connect the VM "bridged" to the company network and enable DHCP in QNX. Then you should be able to connect to the guest OS with the DHCP-assigned address?! Probably I missed the real problem, sorry ;)

Comment: No, unfortunately the QNX machine must stay as the static network in order to work with the system we are developing on. Plus each time i connected to the computer to the network it would change and i would have to find out the address again! And On top of that the QNX box would need to be it approved to be allowed on the network which isnt going to happen because they will only deal with windows. :(

Comment: You need a route from your host to the guest. Identify the interface number (`IF`) of the VM Virtual Ethernetcard (default `vmnet0` if bridged) with `netstat -r` (take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785874/setting-network-adapter-metric-priority-in-windows-7, there's IF 24 for vmnet8 (I think that's the NAT-VM-Adapter). Then in elevated shell: `route add 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 metric 5 if 24` where you plug in your `IF` number of course. Your QNX must also have a route to the IP range of your company network (i.e. to the host). If working use `-p`=persistent in route cmd

Comment: @mpy looks like a good answer, could you add it as one and elaborate a little more? I am trying to work on your comments now.

Comment: I'm not sure, if that approach will work for that scenario, that's why I postponed a real answer. So, if you succeeded with that solution I'll happily write a little bit more detailed answer. If you have a question so far, feel free to ask :)